# Is there a way to hook Windows syscalls on 64-bit builds using a kernel mode driver? (without disabling PG)

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, system-calls, wdk

Is there a way to hook WinAPI system calls on 64-bit builds of Windows, without disabling PG (patch guard)? SSDT hooking using a kernel mode driver is not an option, because patch guard will crash the system when it detects a hook.

For example, a process wants to call the `CreateProcessA`, how do I block (or allow) it depending on the arguments that are passed to it? (However, I would like to know specifically how to hook any or most of the API functions)

Windows Defender does this, if you try running `sc query` it will work, but running `sc stop WinDefend` will trigger a threat alert.

Comment: Install a kernel mode driver

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, kernel mode driver, but I'm asking on how to actually implement it, not the thing (kernel mode driver) that I need. Read the question before answering and/or downvoting.

Comment: Have you tried hooking into ntdll or using detours?

Comment: @J.Doe I checked what's the Microsoft detours, it creates a new process with the hooks. However, I want my hook to be for all processes.

Comment: What windows version are you using? Have you considered wrapping ntdll

Comment: @J.Doe I'm using 64-bit Windows 11

Comment: Use your KM driver to inject into all processes your DLL, then in that DLL hook the APIs you want.

Answer (score -4):

I can provide you with a pseudo code according to my understanding which is somewhat high level for creating a system wide hook . Obviously the actual implementation will be a tedious and lengthy one.

```
// Define a function pointer type for the original CreateProcessA function
// This is necessary to call the original function after interception
Define function pointer LPFN_CREATEPROCESSA

// Declare a global pointer to the original CreateProcessA function
Declare pOriginalCreateProcessA as LPFN_CREATEPROCESSA

// Define the detoured function for CreateProcessA
// This function will replace the original CreateProcessA and perform custom logic
Define function MyCreateProcessA with the same signature as CreateProcessA:
    Log information about the process being created
    Call the original CreateProcessA function to create the process
    Return the result of the original CreateProcessA function

// Entry point for the DLL
Define function DllMain:
    If DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Initialize Detours library
        Begin transaction for Detours library
        Update thread for Detours library
        
        // Detour the CreateProcessA function
        Save the address of the original CreateProcessA function
        Attach the detoured function MyCreateProcessA to CreateProcessA
        
        // Finalize the transaction
        Commit the transaction for Detours library
    End if

    Return TRUE to indicate successful initialization
```